# TSQL: how to tell type of UDF?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using TSQL is there a way to determine whether a UDF returns a Scalar Value or a Table Value?

I examined the results of this query but could not see any differences in functions based on type:

```
select * from sysobjects where type = 'FN'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried joining to `sys.parameters`

```
select * FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P 
ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID where type = 'FN'
```

The `type_desc` column should be either `SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION` or `SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION`

Comment: Not 100% correct. I get 'TF' for a [Table Valued Function]. Check the other answers!

Answer (score 2):

I think `sp_help` does what you want

`sp_help 'dbo.InlineFunction'`

```
Name            Owner   Type                Created_datetime
InlineFunction  dbo     inline function     2012-11-20 10:23:59.260
```

vs...

`sp_help 'dbo.ScalarFunction'`

```
Name            Owner   Type                Created_datetime
ScalarFunction  dbo     scalar  function    2012-11-20 10:23:59.260
```

Comment: nifty - but the one posted by Paul is easier to use in a query. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually you're almost there :)

Scalar functions are listed as being of type `FN` in `sysobjects` and table functions are listed as being of type `TF`.

```
SELECT * from sysobjects WHERE Xtype IN ('FN','TF')
```

or

```
SELECT * from sysobjects WHERE [type] IN ('FN','TF')
```

will return both.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `sysobjects` and `sys.Types` you can  check the UDF and see whether its returning only a `value` or a `table`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCost(@person VARCHAR(10), @month TINYINT)
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
--function body here
```

In the above case it returning only `INT` so the type is `FN`

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCost(@person VARCHAR(10), @month TINYINT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
--function body here
```

Since the function is returning `table` therefore its type is `TF` (Table Value Function)

[UDF Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)